# JS код не работает в IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Бургер-меню и вкладки прекрасно работают в остальных браузерах, но не в IE. Объясните мне, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```js
// Menu
var burgerMenu = document.querySelector(".burger-menu");
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu a");

burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("open");
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.classList.toggle("fade");
    });
});

//Tabs portfolio
var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tabContainer .blocks button");
var tabPanels = document.querySelectorAll(".tabContainer  .projects");

function showPanel(panelIndex,colorCode) {
    tabButtons.forEach(function(node){
        node.style.backgroundColor="";
        node.style.color="";
    });
    tabButtons[panelIndex].style.backgroundColor=colorCode;
    tabButtons[panelIndex].style.color="white";
    tabPanels.forEach(function(node){
        node.style.display="none";
    });
    tabPanels[panelIndex].style.display="flex";
    
}
showPanel(0,'#ffffff');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Причин может быть очень много: `forEach`, `classList`, `display: flex` и даже `querySelector` и `querySelectorAll`. Уточните, *как* именно не работает (ошибка или неправильное поведение) и в какой версии IE не работает.

Comment: Текст ошибки в студию

Comment: @smellyshovel, не работает в версии IE11 . А ошибки выдает: SCRIPT1002: Синтаксическая ошибка script.js (6,41) и SCRIPT5009: "showPanel" не определено index.html (155,42)

Comment: Что значит ""showPanel" не определено index.html"? Оригинальный текст лучше приведите.

Comment: Как скрипт подключается? Где в разметке он подключается? Попробуйте подключить его с атрибутом `defer`: `<script src="ваш скрипт.js" defer></script>`. Хотя, конечно, вряд ли поможет, если в других браузерах все нормально работает. А вообще вместо инлайнового `onclick` воспользоваться `addEventListener`.

Comment: IE11 не поддерживает стрелочные функции, переписывайте на обычные